# How to delete records of orders that is canceled within 5 minutes in database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a record of users' purchasing behavior. However, it is long and includes a lot of redundant data. I want to **delete orders that purchased and deleted within 5 min**

My query so far:
--TABLE 3 COD

```
select z.user_id,
       z.date,
       z.actions,
       x.name,
       x.email,
       x.address
       sum(z.debit) over (partition by z.seller_id order by z.created_at) - 
          sum(z.credit) over (partition by z.seller_id order by z.created_at) 
as balance
from table_1 z

left join

table_2 x

on z.seller_id = x.uid
order by seller_id, created_at
```

For simplicity, i got this result

```
user    actions        credit debit  balance     date
 1    do_action_A      5000    0      5000      2020-01-01 1:00:00     #no need these 2
 1    cancel_A          0     5000      0       2020-01-01 1:03:00     #in result
 1    do_action_A      5000    0      5000      2020-01-01 1:10:00
 1    do_action_b      3000    0      8000      2020-01-01 1:20:00
 1    do_action_c       0     7000    1000      2020-01-01 1:30:00

 2    do_action_A      5000    0      5000      2020-01-01 1:00:00
 2    do_action_B      3000    0      8000      2020-01-01 1:10:00
```

We know that users can only cancel their orders within 5 minutes, unfortunately, there is a lot of cancels. I need to make this data table simple and short so as to track and visualize it easily.

Here is my expectataion:

```
user    actions        credit debit  balance     date

 1    do_action_A      5000    0      5000      2020-01-01 1:10:00
 1    do_action_b      3000    0      8000      2020-01-01 1:20:00
 1    do_action_c       0     7000    1000      2020-01-01 1:30:00

 2    do_action_A      5000    0      5000      2020-01-01 1:00:00
 2    do_action_B      3000    0      8000      2020-01-01 1:10:00
```

Comment: Hitting SQL for each query will be expensive. My suggestion is to have write through cache in between your service and DB to handle fast writes.

Comment: @Seema, indeed, costly, that's why, I thinking about small down data in table

Comment: I generally have two more column in order to identify cancelled orders like `isCancelled = 1` and cancellation_id = 1234 

what you are trying to do is query expensive operation, and I suggest you to find workaround for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using lead()

```
select * from
(
select z.user_id,z.date,z.actions,x.name,
       x.email,x.address,debtit, credit, balance,
lead(z.actions) over(parition by z.user_id order by z.created_at) as next_action
from table_1 z left join table_2 x
on z.seller_id = x.uid
)A where next_action not like '%cancel%' and actions not like '%cancel%'
```

Comment: what if user make 2 purchases and cancels the first one

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu, well, any suggestion in that case ?

Comment: If that is the case, this query wont work. so It cannot be accepted as answer. You need to have isCancelled and CancellationId as I already suggested in the question